# Use a Matrix M as weights of a Dense Layer

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

I would like to create a dense Layer that has weights non trainable, so fixed, and i write the function like this:

```
output_layer_subclass = Dense(classes2_num, activation='softmax',name='classification_subclasses')(b1)
output_layer_class=Dense(M.shape[0], trainable=False, weights=[M], use_bias=False,activation='softmax',name='classification_classes')(output_layer_subclass)
```

where b1 is a Flatten layer. Anyway the M matrix has shape 5x97 and the classes2_num is 97. 
M is a matrix made of zeros and ones.
If I try like this I receive this error when create the model:

```
 Layer weight shape (97, 5) not compatible with provided weight shape (5, 97)
```

Of course if I transpose the M everything works but the important part is that M matrix has to remain with 5x97 shape.

How can I do?

Thanks,
I' m really new to this world hope one day could help the community too.

Edit:

I have tried like:

```
output_layer_subclass = Dense(classes2_num, activation='softmax',name='classification_subclasses')(b1)
output_layer_subclass = Lambda(lambda x: K.dot(M,K.transpose(x)))(output_layer_subclass)

output_layer_class=Dense(classes_num, trainable=False, use_bias=False,activation='softmax',name='classification_classes')(output_layer_subclass)

model = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=[output_layer_subclass,output_layer_class])
```

I receive this error when I run

```
 AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'rank'
```

**Update:**
M is a sparse Matrix of zeros and ones... like

```
array([[1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.,
        1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.,
        1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.,
        1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1.,
        1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1.,
        1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.,
        1.]])
```

Comment: Do you need to use a Dense layer? Why not use a Lambda layer and do the matrix multiplication? If you do not need it to be trainable, it'll be much simpler.

Comment: Can you show me how please? I tried with lambda layer but i received erros... yeah I have to do matrix multiplication

Comment: Could you provide a minimal example where M is defined so I can reproduce the error?

Comment: I wrote in the post how M is created. Is a numpy array of zeros and ones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used the tf.keras.backend.batch_dot method inside a Lambda layer. Hope it helps:

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

classes2_num = 97
classes_num = 10

M = np.array([[1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.,
        1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.,
        1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.,
        1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1.,
        1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1.,
        1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.,
        1.]]).astype(np.float32)
M = np.expand_dims(M, axis=0)

K = tf.keras.backend

inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(100,))
output_layer_subclass = tf.keras.layers.Dense(classes2_num, activation='softmax',name='classification_subclasses')(inputs)
output_layer_subclass = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: K.batch_dot(M, x))(output_layer_subclass)
output_layer_class= tf.keras.layers.Dense(classes_num, trainable=False, use_bias=False,activation='softmax',name='classification_classes')(output_layer_subclass)

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=[output_layer_subclass,output_layer_class])
```

Comment: I have tried your solution but I received this error now Error when checking target: expected lambda_3 to have shape (5,) but got array with shape (97,)... in fact lambda 3 has shape 5